# Are there any denominations that teach a complementarian view of heterosexual marriage, and also recognize same-sex marriages?

Tags: marriage, comparative-christianity, gender, same-sex-marriage, complementarianism

Are there any Christian denominations that teach a complementarian view of opposite-sex marriages (the husband should lead and the wife should submit), while also recognizing same-sex marriages? If so, do they teach that one spouse in a same-sex marriage should submit to the other, or that both have equal roles?

Comment: This is a very good question, and I would love to see an answer, but given how the marriage vows have been wattered down over the decades (the wife is no longer to obey her husband) I would be surprised if any Christian denomiation took a stand on this.  If nobody responds, perhaps placing a bounty might attract some attention?